# UTF-16 file doesn't print correctly

Tags: c, linux, unix, unicode

Expected: Тестирование
Actual: `ÂÕáâØàÞÒÐÝØÕ`

The file was already in UTF-16 but the expected result differ from the actual result. anyone know why this occur. I used both char array and w_char but result is still the same.

Additional: the file is converted from default encoding ISO-8859-15 to UTF16 using iconv.

Your answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: If there's a problem with your code, we need to see the code to fix it.

Comment: The console probably expects UTF-8 encoded data.

Answer (score 4):

```
> echo ÂÕáâØàÞÒÐÝØÕ | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-1 | iconv -f ISO8859-5 -t UTF-8
Тестирование
> echo Тестирование | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-5 | iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8
ÂÕáâØàÞÒÐÝØÕ
```

So this is really ISO8859-5 data interpreted as ISO8859-1. (The UTF-8 conversion pictured are needed because my terminal works in UTF-8). There's no UTF-16 in it anywhere.

This is strange because no one ever uses ISO8859-5.